# Image not showing in grid

Tags: image, data-binding, windows-phone-7, listbox

In my App I want to display a picture inside a listbox, which is linked to objects through databinding. 
However, the picture isn't showing up for some reason, and I can't seem to spot the error. 
I know the picture is in the object, because if I add a new Image object to the XAML, and in code set its source to one of the images from an object, it shows it.

Below is my code in steps:

```
        foreach (Indtastning indt in listBoxIndhold.ItemsSource)
        {
            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(indt.imageName);
            Stream memStream = new MemoryStream(data);
            WriteableBitmap wbimg = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(memStream);
            indt.picture = new Image();
            indt.picture.Source = wbimg;
            //Below is my test image, which shows the picture correctly. 
            testimage.Source = indt.picture.Source;
        }
```

My XAML with the Image:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBoxIndhold" Grid.Row="0"  
                     ItemsSource="{Binding .}"
                     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"   >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ShowGridLines="False">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>

                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=name}" Grid.Column="0"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSmallStyle}"
                                       TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="24"> 
                               <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                    <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                                        <toolkit:MenuItem Tag="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=name}" Header="Rediger"  Click="MenuItem_Click" />
                                        <toolkit:MenuItem Tag="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=name}" Header="Slet"  Click="MenuItem_Click_1"/>
                                    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                               </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                        </TextBlock>

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=description}" Grid.Column="1"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSmallStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                        FontSize="24"> 
                               <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                    <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                                        <toolkit:MenuItem Tag="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=name}" Header="Rediger"  Click="MenuItem_Click" />
                                        <toolkit:MenuItem Tag="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=name}" Header="Slet"  Click="MenuItem_Click_1"/>
                                    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                               </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                        </TextBlock>

                        <Image Source="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=picture}" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="48" Height="48" />

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=amount}" Grid.Column="3"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSmallStyle}"
                                       FontSize="24" > 
                               <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                    <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                                        <toolkit:MenuItem Tag="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=name}" Header="Rediger"  Click="MenuItem_Click" />
                                        <toolkit:MenuItem Tag="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=name}" Header="Slet"  Click="MenuItem_Click_1"/>
                                    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                               </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                        </TextBlock>

                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

My Indtastning class:

```
[DataContract]
public class Indtastning
{
    [DataMember]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double amount { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string description { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool owes { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string imageName;

    public Image picture;


    //Constructor
    public Indtastning(string id , string navn, double beløb, string beskrivelse, bool skylder)
    {
        this.name = navn;
        this.description = beskrivelse;
        this.amount = beløb;
        this.owes = skylder;
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong here? 
It's really anoying as it's one of the last things I need to sort before launching the app.

Comment: Could you provide some more details about the Indtastning class, preferably in code - specifically does it implement INotifyChanged, and is "picture" a public property?

Comment: where is the grid you refer to in the question title?

Comment: Updated with more code. I have not implemented INotifyChanged, perhaps thats what I need to do?

Comment: I've implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged feature on the Picture, but does'nt seem to have worked.

Comment: Fixed it, the INotify wasnt getting the correct binding, so I got that working and the images appeared. Thanks for pointing that out Paul!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved a long time ago.
See my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you saved your images as the content or resource . If the image is resource you will not see it , set it to content and try again . Hope it may help